# Get file extension based on GDAL/OGR Driver

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, drivers

I'm wondering if there is any way of retrieving the correct file extension for GDAL/OGR drivers. For example, if I do something like

```
from osgeo import ogr
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
```

I would like to know what file extension an `ESRI Shapefile` requires. Of course I could create my own mapping, e.g. using a dictionary, but I would need to fill it manually. Aren't there any other possibilities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get a handle to the driver, then check its metadata (`driver.GetMetadataItem(gdal.DMD_EXTENSIONS)`):

```
from osgeo import gdal

raster_drivers = []
vector_drivers = []

for i in range(gdal.GetDriverCount()):

    drv = gdal.GetDriver(i)
    md = drv.GetMetadata_Dict()
        
    d = [drv.ShortName, drv.LongName, drv.GetMetadataItem(gdal.DMD_EXTENSIONS)]

    if 'DCAP_RASTER' in md:
        raster_drivers.append(d)
    if 'DCAP_VECTOR' in md:  # note "if" not "elif" or "else" as some drivers can handle both raster and vector
        vector_drivers.append(d)
```

Comment: Works nicely for GDAL, thanks. Could you extend your answer to OGR, too? Based on your answer, I found that it works similarly, with `meta = driver.GetMetadata()` and `meta['DMD_EXTENSION']`.

Comment: My answer includes OGR (as of GDAL v2.0 released in 2015).  Notice the checks for `DCAP_VECTOR`?  If you're still using the old `ogr`, get with the times and use `gdal.OpenEx` to open vector data ;).